# How to identiy caller mathod from ajaxSuccess in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let me say, I have a document and it have 10 Ajax function calls to the web method. So, I have update in common for all ajax success so, i used

```
$(document)ajaxSuccess()
```

It done the job well.
But, in among the 10 ajax function, I need to ignore only one function's success call to the method or need to handle it different way.

So is there a way to find the caller method details in the **ajaxSuccess** function and handle.

Thanks in advance.
Happy Coding.

Comment: How is `$.ajax()` called?

Comment: Its a normal post method and data type JSON. It has own success functions as well. given the Method URL.

Comment: What is "normal"? Is `$.ajax()` called within an event handler? What is unique about _"only one function's"_ `URL` or how called?  Or are ten `$.ajax()` calls performed at one occasion in succession?

Comment: No, this ten ajax calls i given as example. Ajax is in event handler,load it can be anywhere. because this ajaxSuccess is in a common file that shared among the entire project. I need to distinguish one ajax function that is called on the in every 1 second, done by timeout function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeSend` option of `$.ajax()` settings object to set a `Boolean` flag at `jqXHR` object and `if` condition at `success` callback to check for flag.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/path/to/server",
      beforeSend: function(jqxhr, settings) {
                    jqxhr.not = true;
                  }
    })
}, duration);
```

```
function commonForAllAjaxSuccess(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  if (!jqxhr.not) { // do common stuff } 
  else { // do not do stuff }
}

jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(commonForAllAjaxSuccess);
```